# Assert value of an error message with Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

The following method requires testing

```
if params[:id_at_chain].blank?  
  @error_code_99 = true
  @error_99_messages = @error_99_messages + " id_at_chain missing. "
end
```

this is a sub-method to another method to determine the record creation if that param is not blank

The following test succeeds in asserting that the record is not created

```
  test "no id at chain" do
    assert_no_difference('Article.count') do
      post array_api_v1_articles_path, params: {
      "articles": [
        {
          "code": "000000000000000084",
          }
        ]
      }, as: :json
      puts @error_code_99
      puts @error_99_messages
      assert_equal(" id_at_chain missing. ", @error_99_messages)
    end
  end
```

But the two method instances variables (these are not written to the database) are resulting in nul values and thus the `assert_equal` assertion is not possible.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@error_99_messages` belongs to the controller not the test, so it's nil.
(you can check `@controller.error_99_messages`, maybe)

if your controller's going to response `@error_99_messages` (if parameters invalid) then you should test the error by `assert_match` (or `assert_includes`) the `response.body`

```rb
assert_includes 'id_at_chain missing', response.body
# or
assert_match /id_at_chain missing/, response.body
```

in case you redirect and set error to flash, then

```rb
 assert_response :redirect
 assert_not_nil flash[:error]
 assert_match /your error message/, flash[:error]
```